# Code does not contiue after file is opened via dialogue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite confused right now... I have two modules `open_files` and `start_comparison`. From `start_comparison` I'm calling `open_files`, which is supposed to open the file open dialogue. The user is then supposed to select one file and hit open. Via `start_comparison` the user is supposed to open two files. However sometimes (this is where I'm confused) the code opens the first file, but then simply exit's `start_comparison` occasionally. Sometimes it works, sometimes not, and I have no clue when and why. Below is the code.

What I thought is: When the file dialogue is displayed, one can double click the file and the file will be openend, which would trigger a hidden exit. However, I couldn't confirm this hypthesis. When I step through, everything works fine.

What is your idea about the problem?

```
Sub start_comparison()

Dim cell As Range
Dim control_file_storage_bins As Range
Dim last_row_CONTROLFILE As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws_control_file = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Range("A2:Z1048576").Clear

Call open_files("PHYSICAL STOCK", 1)
Call open_files("STORAGE BINS", 2)

'Copy stock information

With ws_control_file

.Range("A2:A" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value = ws_physical_stock.Range("B2:B" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value
.Range("B2:B" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value = ws_physical_stock.Range("C2:C" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value
.Range("C2:C" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value = ws_physical_stock.Range("J2:J" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value
.Range("D2:D" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value = ws_physical_stock.Range("K2:K" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value
.Range("E2:E" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value = ws_physical_stock.Range("E2:E" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK).Value

End With

Set control_file_storage_bins = ws_control_file.Range("A2:A" & last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK)

For Each cell In rng_STORAGEBIN

If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(control_file_storage_bins, cell.Value) = 0) Then 'Storage Bin empty

    With ws_control_file

        last_row_CONTROLFILE = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(last_row_CONTROLFILE, "A").Value = cell.Value
        .Range("B" & last_row_CONTROLFILE & ":E" & last_row_CONTROLFILE).Value = "BIN EMPTY"

    End With

End If

Next cell

wb_physical_stock.Close (False)
wb_storage_bins.Close (False)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Success!"

End Sub
```

Other procedure:

```
Sub open_files(file_type As String, wb_object As Integer)

Dim last_row_STORAGEBIN As Long

MsgBox "Please select the relevant " & file_type & " extract!"

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    Workbooks.Open (.SelectedItems(1))

    Select Case wb_object

        Case 1 'Physical Stock

            Set wb_physical_stock = ActiveWorkbook

            With wb_physical_stock

                Set ws_physical_stock = ActiveSheet

                last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK = ws_physical_stock.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            End With

        Case 2 'Storage Bins

            Set wb_storage_bins = ActiveWorkbook

            With wb_storage_bins

                Set ws_storage_bins = ActiveSheet

                last_row_STORAGEBIN = ws_storage_bins.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

                Set rng_STORAGEBIN = ws_storage_bins.Range("A2:A" & last_row_STORAGEBIN)

            End With

    End Select

End With

End Sub
```

In case, here is the private variable declaration:

```
Private wb_physical_stock As Workbook, wb_storage_bins As Workbook
Private ws_physical_stock As Worksheet, ws_storage_bins As Worksheet, ws_control_file As Worksheet
Private last_row_PHYSICALSTOCK As Long
Private rng_STORAGEBIN As Range
```

EDIT: I was now checking the procedure `open_files` with breakpoints. If I set a breakpoint BEFORE `Workbooks.Open` and run from there again with F5 everything is fine. However, if I set a breakpoint AFTER `Workbooks.Open`, the breakpoint isn't even triggered. Any ideas?

EDIT2: Previously the macro was started via a short-cut. Now I changed that to an ActiveX-Control and it works fine. Same tested with simple forms and buttons (form control).

Comment: A tip that might or might not be related: Do not rely on `ActiveWorkbook` or `ActiveSheet` unless _you actually need whatever sheet/workbook currently active_. This could lead to unexpected results similar to what you're experiencing.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: Whenever a file is opened, it receive the active status (=ActiveWorkbook / Worksheet). I'm just using this to set my object variables, so I dont need to worry about this :) but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect that opening a file triggers some code, disable events before opening it - this will prevent to execute any (autoexec-) macros withing that file.

Another topic that you should address is that the user might press the "Cancel"-button, else you will run into a runtime error. You can check this with the result of the `show`-method, it will return `False` if the dialog was cancelled

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    if .Show then
        application.EnableEvents = False
        Workbooks.Open (.SelectedItems(1))
        application.EnableEvents = True
        (...)
    else
        ' You have to make up your mind what to do in that case...
    end if
end with
```

Comment: Well, I don't think some actual code is triggered. It seems like there is weird background stuff going on, which I don't understand. However, thank you for the input! I have now taken care of the "Cancel-Button-Issue" :)